# prove that a map is an embedding

Tags: differential-geometry

let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+*}$ be a smooth function.

Prove that $g:\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2: u \rightarrow g(u) = f(u)u$ is an embedding.

I found that $h:  \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1: v \rightarrow h(v)=v/f(v)$ is the inverse of f so f is a homeomorphism. but I can't prove that f is an immersion. Could you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any $t_0\in [0,2\pi]$. Let $\alpha(t):=(\cos t,\sin t)$. Then it is enough to show that $$\left. \dfrac{d}{dt} g(\alpha(t)) \right|_{t=t_0} \neq 0.$$ But this is clear because  $\alpha $ is orthogonal to $\alpha'$,  and $$\dfrac{d}{dt}g(\alpha)=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\alpha))\ \alpha+f(\alpha) \ \alpha'.$$

Comment: I don't find the same formulae after using orthogonality between $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ , I have : $\dfrac{d}{dt}g(\alpha)=f(\alpha) \ \alpha'$, could you please advise?

Comment: The orthogonality is used to show that it is not the zero vector. To find $\frac{d}{dt} g(\alpha)$ you have to use the product rule.

Comment: isn't $\dfrac{d}{dt}g(\alpha)=g'(\alpha)  \alpha' = (f'(\alpha)\alpha + f(\alpha))\alpha' = f(\alpha)\alpha'$ ?

Comment: No. You have to differentiate something of the form $(f(\alpha(t))\cos t,f(\alpha(t))\sin t)$, so you may apply the product rule in each coordinate.

Comment: Right! Thanks you